# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\NuevoBases5L3\Actualizar1.php on line 8

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Pues es esto, me marca este error y sinceramente no se que es lo que está mal, se que dice que se esperaba que se usaran dos parámetros y solo puse uno porque así es el código que nos pasó el profe, sería de mucha ayuda que me ayudaran a saber que tengo mal:(

Es para mostrar una tabla de mi base de datos, pero en ves de la imagen me salen estos errores:[image: n]

Este es el código:

```
     <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $clave = "subsidedaxis8";
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$clave);
    mysqli_select_db($con, "alumnos");
    
    $resultado = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM datos");
    if($resultado === FALSE){
        echo "Fallo: ";
        die (mysqli_error());
    }
     echo "<center class='centro'><header><h1>Consulta realizada</h1></header>";
    echo "<table class='tabla'>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Edad</th>
        </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id_Matricula']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Nombre']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Apellido']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Edad']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
    $registros = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    echo "<br> <span>El numero de registros es: " .$registros. "</span>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    <h3>Escribe la matricula del registro a editar: </h3>
    <form action="Actualizar2.php" method="post">
    <label for="mat">Matricula: </label><input type="text" name="id_matricula" id="mat">
    <input type="submit" value="Editar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El método `mysqli_query` espera como primer parámetro la conexión a la base de datos, prueba pasando primero `$conn` y luego la query

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias:(